# Should I connect jquery-ui.css if jquery-ui.js is connected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Should I connect both `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css` files if the page looks fine with `jquery-ui.js` but without `jquery-ui.css`?

Should I care about `jquery-ui.css`?

P.S. `jquery-ui.js` is definitely needed for my slider, but the slider looks fine even without jquery-ui.css.

Thanks.

Comment: If it works fine then it's probably not necessary. It all depends on what UI features you're using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should.

Most of the jQuery UI widgets depend on style rules defined in that file to perform their layout. Omitting it will give you strange bugs such as, for instance, dialog boxes not being properly rendered, or tabs and accordions not laying out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, For example if you use ui.datepicker on your page,the style of the calender will not be taken if you dont include css file also in your page.